# how to import an external libarary (cplex solver)

Tags: c++, linux, cplex

version1 environment when I do programming. (windows subsystem for linux)

I have to optimize `c++` project to run in both `cplex` and `cbc` solver.
so, I installed `cplex (Linux version)` on `/opt` directory.

When I compiled this project, the compiler can't find the header files.

`cplex` installation path : */opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/*

**error message:**

[image: terminal screenshot with errors]

**make.sh file:**

```
for i in *.cpp
do
NAME=`basename $i .cpp`
g++ -O3 -Wno-deprecated -I. -I/home/optimi/adm_cple/concert20/include -I/home/optimi/adm_cple/cplex90/include -c $NAME.cpp -o $NAME.o
#g++ -O3 -Wno-deprecated -I. -I/home/optimi/adm_cple/concert21/include -I/home/optimi/adm_cple/cplex91/include -c $NAME.cpp -o $NAME.o
done
g++ -o feaspump *.o -L/home/optimi/adm_cple/concert20/lib/i86_linux2_glibc2.3_gcc3.2/static_pic -L/home/optimi/adm_cple/cplex90/lib/i86_linux2_glibc2.3_gcc3.2/static_pic -lilocplex -lcplex -lconcert -lconcertext -lm -lpthread -lncurses
#g++ -o feaspump *.o -L/home/optimi/adm_cple/concert21/lib/x86_RHEL3.0_3.2/static_pic -L/home/optimi/adm_cple/cplex91/lib/x86_RHEL3.0_3.2/static_pic -lilocplex -lcplex -lconcert -lm -lpthread -lncurses
```

Comment: Have you tried to update your WSL before compile ?

Comment: is WSL version affects to this kind of problem??

Comment: WSL is like a little OS. If you tried to compile your code without the necessary libraries on your computer, this fails. So your compiler tells you that it can't find the libraries. Either you don't have them or the link is not good.
Update your WSL can fix the problem if you do not have them

Comment: thank you! i will try about that

Answer (score 0):

Your include paths for the compiler look wrong. Since you installed into `/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/` the include paths in the makefile should be

- `-I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/include`
- `-I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/concert/include`

Similarly, the `-L` argument to the link step should be fixed. It looks like you copied this from a very old template? The path for libaries should be

- `-L/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic`
- `-L/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic`

By the way, CPLEX ships with user examples. You can go for example to `/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/examples/x86-64_linux/static_pic` and type `make blend`. This will compile and link `blend.cpp` and show you all the required command line options for compiling and linking.

Comment: thank you for help. i think examples will be very helpful for me!